# How to split one text area into two textareas?

Tags: javascript, html, split

I have concatenated two text-area value into one text-area value. Now I want split the text-area into it's old two text-area when I click on revert button. Html view image and code given below:
[image: HTML View]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text-center text-primary">TextArea Concatenate and Revert</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="text_area_1"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="text_area_2"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="concatenate()">Concatenate</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <textarea rows="8" cols="100" id="text_area_3"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Revert">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
  function concatenate(){
    document.getElementById("text_area_3").value =
    document.getElementById("text_area_1").value + " " +
    document.getElementById("text_area_2").value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you are not changing anything on the previous text areas, so just update the new one to empty value when reverting.

Comment: to be able to split you have to use a unique separator ( " " - this one is not helpful )

Comment: I will empty the previous two textareas while clicking on submit button.

Comment: then you should probably use a separator.

Comment: Use length of text-boxes to split again using substr function , check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a separator, so that you can split the values back to the textareas.

```
<script>
var one = document.getElementById("text_area_1");
var two = document.getElementById("text_area_2");
var three = document.getElementById("text_area_3");

function concatenate(){
  three.value = one.value + ":" + two.value;
  one.value = "";
  two.value = "";
  }

function revert(){
    var val = three.value.split(":");
    one.value = val[0];
    two.value = val[1];
    three.value = "";
    }
</script>
```

See the example I have created : https://jsfiddle.net/ft05wyxt/

Comment: what if textarea 1 or 2 contains ":" ?

Comment: should change the separator then, totally depends on how it's going to be used.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to concatenate two text-area without any visible separator.

Comment: @Bhansa can u tell me how can I concatenate and split without any visible seperator?

Answer (score 1):

**Using length you can do as following**

```
var textbox1="testt ttets tetstend__";
var textbox2="my second textbox2";

//added a space between;
var mergedTextbox=textbox1+' '+textbox2;

console.log(textbox1.length,textbox2.length,mergedTextbox.length);

var splited1=mergedTextbox.substr(0,textbox1.length);
var splited2=mergedTextbox.substr((textbox1.length+1),textbox2.length);

console.log(splited1,splited2)
```